# How to get current date/time in Javascript without using system time?

Tags: javascript

`new Date()` fetches the current system time. This means, if the current system time is wrong (in my case, the client machine was a Windows system, whose time was set to -4 hours of the current time), `new Date()` will provide a wrong value.

I need a way to get current Date/time of the client without using his machine date/time (probably some way to figure out the timezone where the client is sitting and in turn figure out the time).

How do I do this in JS?

Comment: How is a client's system time "wrong" just because it's in another timezone? Are you just asking how to get the current time in a specific timezone?

Comment: Yes. being in another timezone is not an issue. I need the correct time of that timezone.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+get+accurate+client+time+site%3Astackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working example using [intl resolvedoptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions) and [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```js
const tz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;

fetch("https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/"+tz)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(tz,data.dst,data.datetime));
```

One using user's IP

```js
fetch("https://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data.dst,data.datetime));
```

Comment: Yes! This works! I was a bit skeptical with the timezone, cause if the sytem time is wrong, then the timezone can be wrong as well. Using the public IP will definitely fetch me what I need. Thank you!

Comment: @ScaryTerry Do note that the IP may also be off if the office firewall is in a different timezone than the computer using it. Then you need the location API

Answer (score 2):

You can get time from an API that is on internet, that way you don't have to use client time. The following website where you can make API request to get a time. I hope it helps.

https://worldtimeapi.org/

Here's an example how you can get Timezone based on your IP address from the above API.

Note: Please visit the link above to get API link for the timezone you need and provide here.

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({

    url: "https://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip",
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result)
      $("#tm").text(result.datetime);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="btn" type="button" value="Get Current Time" />
<p id="tm" />
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221574/discussion-on-answer-by-bahroze-ali-how-to-get-current-date-time-in-javascript-w).