# Javascript get users location(country, lang, timezone)

Tags: javascript, location

I would like to collect all info which can be fetched from user without ask any permissions.
I don't want to use any of non-free ip info services and Geolocation

What I have now:

```
timeZoneOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
```

But I want more info about users location.

Comment: That is not possible You can try this one for more accurate timezone for free https://stackoverflow.com/a/63915192/295783

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1: The HTML Geolocation API is used to get the geographical position of a user.

- But it asked user for permission.

Solution 2: Free IP Location API

Check this: https://ipdata.co/

```
$.getJSON('https://geolocation-db.com/json/')
         .done (function(location) {
            $('#country').html(location.country_name);
            $('#state').html(location.state);
            $('#city').html(location.city);
            $('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
            $('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
            $('#ip').html(location.IPv4);
});
```

Solution 3:  PAID IP based API

There is no other solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers mention paid services (ipdata) or free services without the data you need - timezone, etc - (geolocation-db.com)

I believe Abstract has a free plan for their IP geolocation API that includes timezone data among others: https://www.abstractapi.com/ip-geolocation-api

```
$.getJSON("https://ipgeolocation.abstractapi.com/v1/?api_key=****************", function(data) {
       console.log(data.ip_address);
       console.log(data.country);
       console.log(data.timezone);
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BigDataCloud's IP Geolocation API to get maximum data from the IP address of your website visitor.

It provides 10K queries per month for free.

https://www.bigdatacloud.com/ip-geolocation-apis/ip-address-geolocation-api

Output data:

```
{
    "ip": "73.231.131.73",
    "localityLanguageRequested": "en",
    "isReachableGlobally": true,
    "country": {
        "isoAlpha2": "US",
        "isoAlpha3": "USA",
        "m49Code": 840,
        "name": "United States of America",
        "isoName": "United States of America (the)",
        "isoNameFull": "the United States of America",
        "isoAdminLanguages": [
            {
                "isoAlpha3": "eng",
                "isoAlpha2": "en",
                "isoName": "English",
                "nativeName": "English"
            }
        ],
        "unRegion": "Americas/Northern America",
        "currency": {
            "numericCode": 840,
            "code": "USD",
            "name": "US Dollar",
            "minorUnits": 2
        },
        "wbRegion": {
            "id": "NAC",
            "iso2Code": "XU",
            "value": "North America"
        },
        "wbIncomeLevel": {
            "id": "HIC",
            "iso2Code": "XD",
            "value": "High income"
        },
        "callingCode": "1",
        "countryFlagEmoji": ""
    },
    "location": {
        "continent": "North America",
        "continentCode": "NA",
        "isoPrincipalSubdivision": "California",
        "isoPrincipalSubdivisionCode": "US-CA",
        "city": "Milpitas",
        "localityName": "Milpitas",
        "postcode": "95035",
        "latitude": 37.45,
        "longitude": -121.92,
        "plusCode": "849WF32J+22",
        "timeZone": {
            "ianaTimeId": "America/Los_Angeles",
            "displayName": "(UTC-08:00) Pacific Standard Time",
            "effectiveTimeZoneFull": "Pacific Standard Time",
            "effectiveTimeZoneShort": "PST",
            "utcOffsetSeconds": -28800,
            "utcOffset": "-08",
            "isDaylightSavingTime": false,
            "localTime": "2021-02-28T17:11:59.1873233"
        },
        "localityInfo": {
            "administrative": [
                {
                    "order": 2,
                    "adminLevel": 2,
                    "name": "United States of America",
                    "description": "country in North America",
                    "isoName": "United States of America (the)",
                    "isoCode": "US",
                    "wikidataId": "Q30",
                    "geonameId": 6252001
                },
                {
                    "order": 4,
                    "adminLevel": 4,
                    "name": "California",
                    "description": "state of the United States of America",
                    "isoName": "California",
                    "isoCode": "US-CA",
                    "wikidataId": "Q99",
                    "geonameId": 5332921
                },
                {
                    "order": 6,
                    "adminLevel": 6,
                    "name": "Santa Clara County",
                    "description": "county in California, United States",
                    "wikidataId": "Q110739",
                    "geonameId": 5393021
                },
                {
                    "order": 8,
                    "adminLevel": 8,
                    "name": "Milpitas",
                    "description": "city in Santa Clara County, California",
                    "wikidataId": "Q927510",
                    "geonameId": 5373327
                }
            ],
            "informative": [
                {
                    "order": 1,
                    "name": "North America",
                    "description": "continent on the Earth's northwestern quadrant",
                    "isoCode": "NA",
                    "wikidataId": "Q49",
                    "geonameId": 6255149
                },
                {
                    "order": 3,
                    "name": "contiguous United States",
                    "description": "48 states of the United States apart from Alaska and Hawaii",
                    "wikidataId": "Q578170"
                },
                {
                    "order": 5,
                    "name": "Pacific Coast Ranges",
                    "description": "A series of mountain ranges along the Pacific coast of North America",
                    "wikidataId": "Q660304"
                },
                {
                    "order": 7,
                    "name": "95035",
                    "description": "postal code"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "lastUpdated": "2021-02-28T23:39:21.8284029Z",
    "network": {
        "registry": "ARIN",
        "registryStatus": "assigned",
        "registeredCountry": "US",
        "registeredCountryName": "United States of America",
        "organisation": "Comcast Cable Communications, LLC",
        "isReachableGlobally": true,
        "isBogon": false,
        "bgpPrefix": "73.231.0.0/16",
        "bgpPrefixNetworkAddress": "73.231.0.0",
        "bgpPrefixLastAddress": "73.231.255.255",
        "totalAddresses": 65536,
        "carriers": [
            {
                "asn": "AS33651",
                "asnNumeric": 33651,
                "organisation": "Comcast Cable Communications LLC",
                "name": "CMCS",
                "registry": "ARIN",
                "registeredCountry": "US",
                "registeredCountryName": "United States of America",
                "registrationDate": "2005-02-17",
                "registrationLastChange": "2021-01-26",
                "totalIpv4Addresses": 3147776,
                "totalIpv4Prefixes": 217,
                "totalIpv4BogonPrefixes": 0,
                "rank": 152,
                "rankText": "#152 out of 70,908"
            }
        ],
        "viaCarriers": [
            {
                "asn": "AS7922",
                "asnNumeric": 7922,
                "organisation": "Comcast Cable Communications LLC",
                "registeredCountry": "US",
                "registeredCountryName": "United States of America",
                "totalIpv4Addresses": 24911902,
                "rank": 15
            }
        ]
    },
    "confidence": "high",
    "confidenceArea": [
        {
            "latitude": 37.41,
            "longitude": -122.244804
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.42,
            "longitude": -122.244804
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.483982,
            "longitude": -122.23432
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.513985,
            "longitude": -122.22432
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.557896,
            "longitude": -122.20398
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.598026,
            "longitude": -122.17369
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.632973,
            "longitude": -122.134514
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.66151,
            "longitude": -122.08782
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.68264,
            "longitude": -122.03526
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.69562,
            "longitude": -121.97865
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.7,
            "longitude": -121.92
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.7,
            "longitude": -121.89
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.6962,
            "longitude": -121.83531
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.684914,
            "longitude": -121.782295
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.666485,
            "longitude": -121.732544
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.64147,
            "longitude": -121.687584
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.62147,
            "longitude": -121.657585
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.582153,
            "longitude": -121.610214
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.535625,
            "longitude": -121.57468
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.484097,
            "longitude": -121.55265
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.43,
            "longitude": -121.5452
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.42,
            "longitude": -121.5452
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.364517,
            "longitude": -121.55305
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.311806,
            "longitude": -121.5762
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.26449,
            "longitude": -121.61351
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.25449,
            "longitude": -121.62351
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.22382,
            "longitude": -121.65991
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.19844,
            "longitude": -121.70228
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.188442,
            "longitude": -121.722275
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.16475,
            "longitude": -121.78348
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.15206,
            "longitude": -121.84966
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.150974,
            "longitude": -121.91773
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.161533,
            "longitude": -121.98451
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.17153,
            "longitude": -122.02451
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.17153,
            "longitude": -122.02451
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.19254,
            "longitude": -122.085304
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.223186,
            "longitude": -122.1392
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.262123,
            "longitude": -122.18382
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.307613,
            "longitude": -122.21719
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.357647,
            "longitude": -122.23782
        },
        {
            "latitude": 37.41,
            "longitude": -122.244804
        }
    ],
    "securityThreat": "unknown",
    "hazardReport": {
        "isKnownAsTorServer": false,
        "isKnownAsVpn": false,
        "isKnownAsProxy": false,
        "isSpamhausDrop": false,
        "isSpamhausEdrop": false,
        "isSpamhausAsnDrop": false,
        "isBlacklistedUceprotect": false,
        "isBlacklistedBlocklistDe": false,
        "isKnownAsMailServer": false,
        "isKnownAsPublicRouter": false,
        "isBogon": false,
        "isUnreachable": false,
        "hostingLikelihood": 0,
        "isHostingAsn": false,
        "isCellular": false
    }
}
```